# Multiple criteria If & Isblank Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been working on this for a day or so now but it is beyond my poor excel knowledge and I can't get it right?

I am trying to write a formula that does this:

If A1=1 and B1=2 and C1="Yes" then D1 but If A1=1 and B1=2 and C1="No" then E1 but if If A1=1 and B1=2 and C1=isblank then ""

I want the formula to look at Cell A1 and see if it contains the number 1 then
look at Cell B1 and see if it contains the number 2 then
look at Cell C1 and see if it contains the text "yes" and if it does return the contents of Cell D1 but
if Cell C1 contains the text "no" then return the contents of Cell E1 but 
if Cell C1 isblank (has no text or numbers) then do nothing.

Any help or suggestions would be gratefully received.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ahh sorry I see what you mean - my aim is better expressed as - 
favorite
I have been working on this for a day or so now but it is beyond my poor excel knowledge and I can't get it right?

I am trying to write a formula that does this:

If A1=1 and B1=2 and C1="Yes" then D1 but If A1=1 and B1=2 and C1="No" then E1 but if If A1=isblank and B1=isblank and C1=isblank then "" <--meaning do nothing>

Comment: `If(AND(A1=1,B1=2), IF(C1="Yes", D1, IF(C1="No", E1, ""), "")`

Comment: You haven't covered all the cases. What do you want to happen when A1 is not 1, B1 is not 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=IF(AND(A1=1,B1=2,C1="Yes"),D1,IF(AND(A1=1,B1=2,C1="No"),E1,IF(AND(A1=1,B1=2,C1=""),"","whatever")))
```

where "whatever" represents the ***Else***

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try :)